# Why is my pointer disappearing?

Tags: c, pointers

I have a class that is meant to return a char** by splitting one char* into sentences. I can allocate the memory and give it values at a certain point, but by the time I try to return it, it's completely missing.

```
char **makeSentences(char *chapter, int *nSentences){
int num = *nSentences;
char* chap = chapter;
char **sentences;
sentences = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * num);
int stops[num + 1];
stops[0] = 0;
int counter = 0;
int stop = 1;
while (chap[counter] != '\0'){
    if (chap[counter] == '.'){
        stops[stop] = counter + 1;
        printf("Place: %d\nStop Number: %d\n\n", counter, stop);
        stop++;
    }
    counter++;
}
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
    int length = stops[i+1] - stops[i];
    char characters[length+1];
    memcpy(characters, &chap[stops[i]], length);
    characters[length] = '\0';
    char *sentence = characters;
    sentences[i] = sentence;
    printf("%s\n",sentence);
    printf("%s\n", sentences[i]);
}
char* testChar = sentences[0];
printf("%s\n", sentences[0]);
printf("%s]n", testChar);
return sentences;
}
```

The last two printing lines don't print anything but a newline, while the exact same lines (in the for loop) print as expected. What is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is these three lines:

```
char characters[length+1];
char *sentence = characters;
sentences[i] = sentence;
```

Here you save a pointer to a *local variable*. That variable `characters` will go out of scope every iteration of the loop, leaving you with an "array" of stray pointers.

While not standard in C, almost all systems have a `strdup` function whichg duplicates a string by calling `malloc` and `strcpy`. I suggest you use it (or implement your own).

Comment: @JC97 Please mark the answer as accepted if you're satisfied. It is described [in the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) how to do it.